# AWS S3 policies confusions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, amazon-iam

I would like to give read (download) right to a single user.
I am confused about what I should use:

Should I use

- The Bucket Policy Editor from the S3 interface
- The inline policies for the user and specify read permissions (from IAM interface)
- Activate "Any Authenticated AWS User" has the right to read (from s3 interface) and then use inline permissions for more granularity ?

I used the inline policies and it won't work:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowUserToReadObject",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectTorrent"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::staging/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::prod/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I use Boto:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key
import sys, os

AWS_KEY = ''
AWS_SECRET = ''



from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

conn = S3Connection(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET)

bucket = conn.get_bucket('staging')
for key in bucket.list():
    print key.name.encode('utf-8')
```

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "listing_bucket_files.py", line 20, in <module>
    bucket = conn.get_bucket('staging')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 503, in get_bucket
    return self.head_bucket(bucket_name, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 536, in head_bucket
    raise err
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't assign `"s3:ListBucket"` permission, that the account was stopped at the access to buckets of `staging` and `prod`, then has no permission to access the files/folders in these buckets.

Remember you have to seperate the code as below, and don't add `/*` after bucket name.

```
   "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::staging",
                "arn:aws:s3:::prod",
            ]
        },
```

Comment: Thank you, I kept my code as it is and added `s3:ListBucket`.